# I want to align a flat button to the start along with the rest of the elements but some property is preventing it

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to align a flatbutton to the left along with the other elements but some property is preventing me from doing so.

[image: flutter outline screenshot]

Here's the code:

```
      body: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(top: 60, left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
                onPressed: () {
                  _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
                },
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.list,
                  size: 30,
                  color: Colors.tealAccent,
                ),
              ),
```

what can I do here?

Comment: try remove padding for Column@Ashwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flat Button automatically adds phantom padding to it, [see this issue.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3678) The solution is to use the [InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) widget. Your example implemented with `InkWell` to remove the padding in the button would look like this:

```
Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(top: 60, left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  InkWell(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.list,
                      size: 30,
                      color: Colors.tealAccent,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {}
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

The advantage of using an InkWell instead of a `GestureDetector` is it gives you the Material looking splash effect that a `FlatButton` would have. If that is undesirable, than you can replace the `InkWell` widget with a `FlatButton`.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed. Learned something new too.

Comment: @Ashwin happy to help, if it worked please upvote too:) Thanks!

Comment: I'm quite new here. Got only 13 rep. It says I need to have at least 15 rep to upvote :(

Comment: @Ashwin oh, that's my bad I forgot that.... Have a great day!

Comment: Hi Gabe! I'm at 15 now. I can now give you your well deserved upvote!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `GestureDetector` instead of `FlatButton` like code below:

```
Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              child: Padding(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(top: 60, left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30),
                  child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
                          },
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.list,
                            size: 30,
                            color: Colors.tealAccent,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text('hhfhdhh')
                      ])))
        ])));
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it was helpful for you please vote it up.

Comment: I'm quite new here. Got only 13 rep. It says I need to have at least 15 rep to upvote :(

Comment: That's Right. Good luck my friend.

Comment: Hi Ali! I'm at 15 now. I can now give you your well deserved upvote!